# Not getting the value of an input element inside <td> while exporting table to csv

Tags: jquery, export-to-csv, html-tableextract

Html code

```html
<html>
<td><input id="id1"  value="3000" a type="text" /></td>
</html>
```

I need the value 3000 to be in the csv file please help

My  Function

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">





        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

                }


</script>
```

write now iam getting the csv file with data as ,"","","","","","","",

Comment: I have just copied part of my code please ignore mistakes in above code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">


    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
                var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)')
                    ,$rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)')
                    // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
                    // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
                    ,tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11) // vertical tab character
                    ,tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0) // null character
                    // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
                    ,colDelim = '","'
                    ,rowDelim = '"\r\n"';
                    // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
                    var csv = '"';
                    csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
                    csv += rowDelim;
                    csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';
                    // Data URI
                    var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
                $(this)
                    .attr({
                    'download': filename
                        ,'href': csvData
                        ,'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
                });
                //------------------------------------------------------------
                // Helper Functions 
                //------------------------------------------------------------
                // Format the output so it has the appropriate delimiters
                function formatRows(rows){
                    return rows.get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                        .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                        .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim);
                }
                // Grab and format a row from the table
                function grabRow(i,row){
                     
                    var $row = $(row);
                    //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
                    var $cols = $row.find('td'); 
                    if(!$cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th');  
                    return $cols.map(grabCol)
                                .get().join(tmpColDelim);
                }
                // Grab and format a column from the table 
                function grabCol(j,col){
                    var $col = $(col),
                    $inputs = $col.find('input');
                    if($inputs.length >=1){
      var $tot='';
                        $.each((jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify($inputs.map(function(k,inp)
                        {
       var $inputElement = $(inp),
       $text=$inputElement.val();
       
       var $object=JSON.stringify($text);
       //var newObject = JSON.parse(object);
       console.log(JSON.parse($object));
       return JSON.parse($object);
       
      })))),function(){
       for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
        $tot+=this[i];}
       }); // escape double quotes
      return $tot;
     }
     else
     $text=$col.text();
     return $text;
                }
            }

       
 
 </script>
```

```js
 $(".export88").click( function (event) {
        // CSV
        alert("clicked");
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#datatab>table'), 'Sales_Data.csv']);
        
        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    })
```

```html
<a href="#" class="export88" style="color: White;">Export</a>
```